# Executing 'CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG' script during DB initialization (EF 6.1 - CF)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I using Entity Framework 6.1 (Code First) on Sql Server. Inside my database initializer I want to execute a script setting up a Full Text Search Catalog:

```
            using (var context = new DataAccessContext())
            {
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(createFullTextSearchCommandString);
            }
```

That's the script I trying to execute (value of 'createFullTextSearchCommandString'):

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MyFTS
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

I getting the following error:

> CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user
>   transaction.

OK, this statement cannot be executed under transaction, got it. But - i don't care about transaction. All I want is to execute this statement. Is any way to avoid transaction creation or somehow to bypass it?